# How to install apt-get when building docker image from pytorch/manylinux-cpu base image?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, pytorch, apt-get

I am trying to build a docker image from a cpu based pytorch base image. It works fine with the gpu base image, but need to save some space and run on cpu. So i use the following Dockerfile to build my image, but it seems that I need to install apt-get. So now, the question is either, how can I get the apt-get in this container, or is there an alternative? Like for alpine based containers, I saw there is apk instead of apt-get. But the problem is, I do not even know how to figure out the container base for my base image. I assumed it is linux.

```
#FROM pytorch/pytorch:latest
FROM pytorch/manylinux-cpu:latest

RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install waitress flask scikit-learn torch_optimizer pandas geffnet

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
```

The error i receive is:

```
$ docker build . -t cpu_web_app
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.31GB
Step 1/8 : FROM pytorch/manylinux-cpu:latest
 ---> f28a327c8487
Step 2/8 : RUN set -xe     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y python-pip
 ---> Running in 31cead57ae3d
+ apt-get update
/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c set -xe     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y python-pip' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Thanks for your help and any hints!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out now, you need to look inside the base image and figure out which distribution of linux you use. In this case, CENTos, and then just follow up the standard procedure for this distro